# can i use ffmpeg to stream my desktop with an end to end latency below 80ms for a resolution of 1920x1080@30fps?

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg using direct show capture filter has an end to end latency of 200-350ms for 30fps using ultrafast and 8 threads. 
End to end is from Source machine to target Raspberry Pi running hardware optimized omx-player.